# Google Play Game Services with multiple user accounts

Tags: google-plus, google-play-games

I've just released a new version of my game with the integration of Google Play Game Services for the leaderboards and achievements. For a better understanding of my issue, here an example:

When the user connects, a popup window ask which account to use. Let's say I'm using account A. However, in the G+ app, it's account B that is connected.

When the user go to the leaderboards, he can also share a message to his friends but, that's not A's friends! That's the friends of the G+ connected account: B.

It looks like a bug for me but that's not all. Now, I have disconnected B from the G+ app and connected A instead. But it's also showing that I have no contact in my circle playing my game. That's not true. I can see in the public scores a friend of mine.

Am I misunderstanding something? Or is it a bug? For the last issue, is it just a problem of refresh? (I've tried the refresh button with no luck)

Comment: Now I have a score from a friend who did not published publicly. I guess that scores published publicly does not appear in both my contacts and the public leaderboard... But I would prefer to see the scores of all my friends in one leaderboard...

Comment: Did I get it right or are you trying to use the account B while connected as A? What's the sense? Of course you have to log out and in again to use the other account in any way. I don't know about the empty circles though.

Comment: @Finnboy11 The problem is that when you are *in* the game and a popup asks you to select an account, you assume that the circles displayed are yours. But instead it's the ones of the account connected in the G+ app. It is really really confusing.